# Windows 10 - Programmatically remove new shortcut from appearing in "recently added" in startmenu

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10, startmenu

I am writing code for my product's installer. I am creating a shortcut using C++ linkShell. I don't want my product's shortcut to be added to the "recently added" list in Windows 10 start menu.

I tried to set the PKEY_AppUserModel_ExcludeFromShowInNewInstall to TRUE.
This removes the highlighted yellow color in Windows 7 start menu.
But this does not work for Windows 10.

Is there a way to remove recent installed app shortcuts from "recently added" start menu list in Windows 10?

Comment: Find out where it's at in the registry, get necessary privileges (if any), remove it.

Comment: If there's a new shortcut in my computer, I wanna know about it. Not only this, but I also don't like external applications messing with my system registry when is not explicity needed and in keys that clearly do not belong to it (such as the keys for the recently added shorcuts). In short: your program is running in another person's computer. Don't make assumptions about what that other person wants or expects to happen when installing your program. If they don't want to know the recently added shortcuts, they can disable it themselves.

Comment: @CássioRenan - You are correct. My product is having multiple shortcuts and I dont want one shortcut like uninstall or deactivate to be listed in recently added list. User still is aware of what they installed because I am creating those shortcuts in start menu. I just dont want in recently added.

Comment: @vedikaseth BTW you are not supposed to create a shortcut for unistalling a product. Uninstalling should be done from the Configuration panel.